# how to show text in lower case in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I  try to implement tabs in android .I am able to implement tab in android but my android text display in capital .I don’t want to show my tab text in capital letter .
can we show text in same format as given in code

here is my manifest file

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

**manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.naveen.tabsfavourite" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**java code**

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    ViewPager viewPager;
    FragmentpagerAdapter fragmentpagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ActionBar actionBar =getActionBar();
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        fragmentpagerAdapter =new FragmentpagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(fragmentpagerAdapter);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Stations").setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("fav Station").setTabListener(this));
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int i) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
}
```

Comment: First of all that tab you are using to way too outdated. . See android design support library for new approach and implementation.

Comment: could you please give new link

Comment: try to using toLowerCase() method after string

Comment: Check out : http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html

Answer (score 3):

you have two options to do that

1- you can set dynamically 
  - if you are not sure the text is in lower case you have to convert that in to lower case using string.toLowerCase(); and you have to set set  the behaviour of TextView

```
textView.setText(yourString.toLowerCase());
textView.setAllCaps(false);
```

2- you can set the behavior of in xml itself

```
   <TextView
    ....
    ....
    android:textAllCaps = "false"
    />
```

Comment: you have to call textView.setText(yourString.toLowerCase()); anyway

Answer (score 2):

Use [Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) > Tabs

Add styles for your Tablayout in styles.xml

```
<style name="TabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

then add that attribute as:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextAppearance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I tested it. It'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try any of these following things, However you have tried the first one i have mentioned below, You can try the other one

- Use android:textAllCaps="false" in your layout-v21
- Check your style for Allcaps

  ```
  <style name="Theme.CustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="android:textAppearanceButton">@style/CustomTheme.ButtonTextAppearance</item>
  </style>

  <style name="CustomTheme.ButtonTextAppearance" parent="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
  <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
  <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
  </style>
  ```

Comment: I was editing the same. You can follow last approach it should work for you

Answer (score 0):

> Try this code. Hope your problem resolve

```
 TextView tv =  (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(index).findViewById(android.R.id.title); 
   tv.setAllCaps(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin's extension function to convert the string into lowercase

```
val name = "ABC"
val lowercaseName = name.lowercase()
```

Answer (score -1):

Be shure that you **write your text in the strings.xml in lower case**. Or convert that into lower case using string.toLowerCase() as [droidev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2769892/droidev) mentioned above.